# Testing pairwise differences for correlated pairs

Tags: paired-data, independence

Here is my setup:

- I have `B=100` pairs of samples `(a_i1, a_i2) i=1..B`
- Unfortunately, unlike in classical paired samples, for both groups `k=1..2`: `(a_ik) i=1..B` are **correlated** samples, supposedly from `N(mu_k, sigma_k)`

I would like to know how I could rigorously test for differences between `mu_1` and `mu_2`.
In particular, I can think of permutation test and paired t-test, but I don't really get how I should adapt them to take into account the non-independence between samples?

Here is a bit more of context on the nature of data:

- my main dataset is a longitudinal dataset
- I build some dynamic predictions on top of it (e.g. forecasting value at last timepoint knowing data of first 3 timepoints for a given subject), based on `k` different predictive models
- the `(a_ik)` is a metric evaluating prediction accuracy of the predictive model `k` [e.g. (adjusted) mean absolute error] for a given subset `i` of all possible predictions (we do not evaluate on the whole dataset, because it would not be representative of our target predictions). The non-independence of `(a_ik)_i` comes from the fact that subsets are not pairwise disjoint.

Comment: You can't decide unless you adopt stronger assumptions (relating to the structure of the covariance matrix and the magnitudes of its entries).  This problem usually arises in time series analysis and sometimes with other stochastic processes or longitudinal datasets, so if you could tell us about the nature of the data and describe the problem you actually have (rather than abstracting out such important information) then we might be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a bit of context on data (longitudinal dataset analysis indeed).